# In R, match function for rows or columns of matrix

Tags: r

The [value matching function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/match.html) in `R` is very useful. But from my understanding, it does not sufficiently support two or high dimensional inputs.

For example, assume `x` and `y` are matrices of same number of columns, and I would like to match rows of `x` to rows of `y`. The 'R' function call `match(x,y)` does not do so. The same insufficiency occurs to inputs of lists.

I have implemented my own version of it called `matchMat(xMat, yMat)` (attached below), but I am wondering what is you solution to this task.

```
matchMat = function(xMat, uMat, dimn=1) {
    ind = rep(-1, dim(xMat)[dimn])
    id = 1 : dim(uMat)[dimn]
    for (i in id) {
        e = utilSubMat(i, uMat, dimn)
        isMatch = matchVect(e, xMat, dimn)
        ind[isMatch] = i
    }
    return(ind)
}

matchVect = function(v, xMat, dimn) {
    apply(xMat, dimn, function(e) {
        tf = e == v
        all(tf)
    })
}

unittest_matchMat = function() {
    dimn = 1
    uMat = matrix(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5), ncol=2, byrow=T)
    ind = sample(dim(uMat)[1], 10, replace=T)
    print(ind)
    xMat = uMat[ind, ]
    rst = matchMat(xMat, uMat, dimn)
    print(rst)
    stopifnot(all(ind == rst))

    xMat2 = rbind(c(999, 999), xMat, c(888, 888))
    rst2 = matchMat(xMat2, uMat, dimn)
    print(rst2)
    stopifnot(all(c(-1, ind, -1) == rst2))
    print('pass!')   
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`match` will work on `list`s of atomic vectors. So to match rows of one matrix to another, you could do:

```
match(data.frame(t(x)), data.frame(t(y)))
```

`t` transposes the rows into columns, then `data.frame` creates a `list` of the columns in the transposed matrix.

Comment: Here is a minimal example, and I wonder why it does not work:

`A <- data.frame(x = 1:6, y = 2:7)`, `B <- data.frame(x = 1:8, y = c(2:8, 10))`, `match(data.frame(t(A)), data.frame(t(B)))`. It outputs `[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA` only.

Comment: The reason is that `class(c(2:7))` gives `[1] "integer"` whereas `class(c(2:8, 10))` gives `[1] "numeric"`. Lists are not the same if they don't contain data of the same type but that proves that this solution is not handy to use.

Answer (score 5):

The function `row.match` in the package `prodlim` allows you to identify the rows in one matrix that are also found (identical) in another matrix. Very convenient and easy to use.

```
library(prodlim)
row.match(x,y)
```

Comment: It seems like this is only returning the first match instead of all

Comment: @derp92 `match` does exactly the same. From the documentation: `match returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument in its second.`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `asplit` to create a `list` which can be used by match. But the manual says *lists are converted to character vectors* and *Matching for lists is potentially very slow and best avoided except in simple cases*.

```
match(asplit(x, 1), asplit(y, 1))
#[1] NA  1  2
```

So maybe using `interaction` or `paste` is an option.

```
match(interaction(data.frame(x)), interaction(data.frame(y)))
#[1] NA  1  2

match(apply(x, 1, paste, collapse =" "), apply(y, 1, paste, collapse =" "))
#[1] NA  1  2
```

Data:

```
(x <- matrix(1:9, 3))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    7
#[2,]    2    5    8
#[3,]    3    6    9

(y <- matrix(2:10, 3))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    5    8
#[2,]    3    6    9
#[3,]    4    7   10
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do that without using any functions:

Suppose  `adj1` is the `3*3` matrix with both *colnames* and *row.names* being `c('V1','V2','V3')` and `vec1` is the order you want your matrix to be transformed into:

```
vec1 <- c('V2','V3','V1')
```

You could simply using the following code:

```
adj1[vec1,vec1]
```

Which will do you the magic.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `apply`:

```
z <- apply(x, 1, function(a) apply(y, 1, function(b) all(a==b)))
```

This will generate a matrix with `nrow(x)` rows and `nrow(y)` columns, whose entries mark the indices where there is a match.